# unable to get the registered id from gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

- I am using this [Android
  hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
  tutorial to get the push notification.
- I couldn't get the registration id from gcm because GCMIntentService
  class is runnning after register id becomes null in mainActivity.
- Registration id is always null when executing the mainActivity.After
  sometime only I am getting the registration id from gcmintentService.
- I am using all the gcm codes in root package.
- Below I have posted codes relevant to that.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(MainActivity.this);

    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(MainActivity.this);

    lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    Log.e("mHandleMessageReceiver", ""+mHandleMessageReceiver);

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(MainActivity.this);

    Log.e("CheckRegId", ""+regId);


    // Check if regid already presents

    if (regId.equals("")) {
    // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
    GCMRegistrar.register(MainActivity.this, SENDER_ID);

    Log.e("RegIDNull", "RegIdNull");

    } else {

    // Device is already registered on GCM

    if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(MainActivity.this)) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {


    Log.e("HitAynscReg", "HitAynscReg");


    mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    ServerUtilities.register(MainActivity.this, appVersionNameStr,regId, deviceUserId, getDeviceNameStr, "Android", androidVersionNameBuilder.toString(), 
                                                String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude), address+", "+areaName+", "+city, userid );


    return null;
    }

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    mRegisterTask = null;

    }

    };
    mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);

    }
    }
```

**Manifest:**

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.app.steve.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.app.steve.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

   <application
    android:name="com.golive.entertainment.volley.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/client_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     .......
     .......
     <activity
        android:name="com.app.steve.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>


      <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.app.steve" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

      </application>
```

**GCMIntentService.java:**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);

        Log.e("GCMIntentServiceConstructorCalling", "Test");
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

        Log.e("GCMIntentServiceRegID", ""+registrationId);      

        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");

        ServerUtilities.register(GCMIntentService.this, MainActivity.appVersionNameStr,registrationId, MainActivity.deviceUserId, MainActivity.getDeviceNameStr, "Android", MainActivity.androidVersionNameBuilder.toString(), 
                String.valueOf(MainActivity.latitude), String.valueOf(MainActivity.longitude), MainActivity.address+", "+MainActivity.areaName+", "+MainActivity.city, MainActivity.userid );


    }
```

If I run the GCMIntentService before that registration id code in mainACtivity, I can get the expected result.Anyone know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding this below line in SplashScreenActivity.java class:

```
 GCMRegistrar.register(MainActivity.this, SENDER_ID);
```

Then after clicking the login button, I am running the GCM Code in MainActivity.java.So I can get the registration id.Because we can get some time to get the registration id from gcm.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Manifest.

```
<!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".utils.gcm.ListenerServiceGCM"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".utils.gcm.InstanceIDListenerServiceGCM"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".utils.gcm.RegistrationIntentServiceGCM"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>

    <service android:name=".notifications.NotifyService" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".notifications.OrderResponseReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.notif.test.action_accept" />
            <action android:name="com.notif.test.action_reject" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: What is the significance of **com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare **GCMIntentService** class directly in the package itself, e.g.

```
com.example.demoapp.GCMIntentService;
```

You don't get the Registration id if GCMIntentService  class is declared inside any folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).

Google provides the Instance ID API to handle the creation and updating of registration tokens. To use this API, include InstanceIDListenerService in the manifest:

```
<service android:name="[.MyInstanceIDService]" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

To obtain a token, call instanceID.getToken, providing the app server's sender ID and setting the scope to GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE. Do not call this method in the main thread; instead, use a service that extends IntentService as shown:

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
// ...

@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // ...
    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

    // ...
}

// ...
```

}

Once you've received your registration token, make sure to send it to your server.

Answer (score -1):

```
Here is the implementation which I have done in my project.    
    GCMBroadcastReciever.java

        public class GCMBroadcastReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Attach component of GCMIntentService that will handle the intent in background thread
                ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                        GCMIntentServices.class.getName());
                // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
                startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
                setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            }
        }

        GCMIntentService.java


        public class GCMIntentServices extends IntentService {

            public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

            public GCMIntentServices() {
                super(GCMIntentServices.class.getName());
            }

            @Override
            protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

                if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

                    // read extras as sent from server
                    String message = extras.getString("message");
                    String serverTime = extras.getString("timestamp");
                    sendNotification("Message: " + message + "\n" + "Server Time: "
                            + serverTime);
                }
                // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
                GCMBroadcastReciever.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
            }

            private void sendNotification(String msg) {
                mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_up_blue_soft)
                        .setContentTitle("Notification from GCM")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);

                mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
            }
        }


          private class GCMRegistrationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    }
                    try {
                        regId = gcm.register(GlobalConfig.YOUR_SENDER_ID);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return regId;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        Log.e("reg", result);

                        GlobalCommonMethods.saveValueOnUserPrefernces(MainActivity.this, result, "reg_id");
        //                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "registered with GCM"+regId,
        //                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //                reg();
                    }
                }

            }


    manifest.xml

       <receiver
                android:name=".helperclass.GCMBroadcastReciever"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="com.geeks.schoolmanagement"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <service android:name=".helperclass.GCMIntentServices"/>
            <!-- make sure to add google-play-services_lib from  project properties->android->library-->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
        <!-- For vibrating device -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <!-- For receiving GCM messages -->
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <!-- For protecting GCM messages so that only your app can receive them -->
        <permission
            android:name="com.geeks.schoolmanagement.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.geeks.schoolmanagement.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```